# Encrypting connection string: "This operation does not apply at runtime"

Tags: c#

I have a console application and it has app.config. When I run this code:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            ConnectionStringsSection connSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("connectionStrings") as 
                                                    ConnectionStringsSection;
            if (connSection != null)
            {
                if (!connSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
                    connSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");

                else
                    connSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

I get error: "This operation does not apply at runtime". I also tried giving permissions to my app.config but no luck.

What can the issue?

Comment: At which line exactly the error appears?

Comment: at this line: "connSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");"

Comment: The class double-checks that you don't try to encrypt the connection string at runtime.  That doesn't make sense, it has to be done at design time in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense for it to be done in runtime? How can it be done in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
 static void Main()
 {


     // Get the current configuration file.
     System.Configuration.Configuration config =
             ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
             ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

     ConnectionStringsSection connSection = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as
                                             ConnectionStringsSection;

     if (connSection != null)
     {
         if (!connSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
             connSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(null);

         else
             connSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
     }

     connSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;

     config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Comment: +1 did the trick. However it encrypted my ConsoleApplication5.exe.config where ConsoleApplication5 is the applicationname. My original app.config in my project folder is still unencrypted. Any idea why?

Comment: because you are opening the app.config for the application you're currently running. The app.config filename is changd to YourApp.exe.config and copied to the output directory. The output is put in bin\debug or release. So it takes the config file in that folder and encrypts it.

Comment: NO LONGER WORKS.  M$ have changed the implementation so that ForceSave and ProtectSection only work a runtime when ADDING a section

Answer (score 4):

I think you are supposed to use the `OpenExeConfiguration` method in this scenario:

```
  System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(pathToExecutable);

  ConnectionStringsSection connSection = 
    config .GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;
```

the parameter `pathToExecutable` should be the full path to the exe of your application, for example: "C:\application\bin\myapp.exe"

Comment: The code ran without any exception but my connecting string didn't get encrypted :o. I used this:  connSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");

Comment: @Jaggu: I assume you have a 'DataProtectionConfigurationProvid‌​er', right?

Comment: @Jaggu: Does it work when you use any of the built-in providers? For example 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to encrypt sections at runtime, you encrypt them before runtime with the aspnet_setreg.exe tool.  [More info here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329290)

ASP.NET then *reads* the encrypted sections at runtime transparently.

Comment: Are you sure this also applies to console applications?

Comment: Good point guys, I had my mind in asp.net.  The code above shouldn't work in a web context, that's for sure.  But as for a console app, I'm not sure.  I would THINK that you still couldn't mess with the current app's config file at runtime, but you could modify a DIFFERENT app's config, which is what the code Jaggu mentions does.

Comment: No, but it is C# code. So I guess it should run because we have equivalent app.config as against web.config